# why is python faster than c ++ when inserting into a database?

Tags: python, c++, sqlite

I have an array of 100 elements called "items"

Python (take about 1 sec):

```
for item in items:
           cur.execute("INSERT INTO list VALUES (?)",(item,))
db.commit()
```

C++ (9 sec):

```
for ( auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it  ) {
    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO list VALUES (?)");
    std::string item = *it;
    qry.addBindValue(item);
    qry.exec();
```

C++ without `prepare` (9 sec):

```
for ( auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it  ) {
    std::string item = *it;
    qry.exec("INSERT INTO list VALUES ('"+item+"')");
```

Basically my question is whether there is a way to use `insert` in C++ as fast as in Python.

Comment: The fact that you `commit` once at the end of your python and don't seem to be running in a transaction in c++ might account for the difference.

Comment: `qry.exec("INSERT INTO list VALUES (*item)");` isn't actually going to do what you want.  Depending on what `*item` is you need something like: `qry.exec("INSERT INTO list VALUES (" + *item + ")");`

Comment: Remember, you can prepare once and bind/execute multiple times.

Comment: Even the python method isn't optimised because you could be using `executemany`. I suspect your benchmark is flawed

Comment: Your updated code is still flawed. `qry.exec("INSERT INTO list VALUES (item)");` will insert the word "item" for every record.  You need `qry.exec("INSERT INTO list VALUES (" + item +")");` or possibly `qry.exec(("INSERT INTO list VALUES (" + item +")").c_str());`

Comment: You don't normally prepare a statement every time you are about to use it. Prepare it once, use many times.

Comment: You may want to remove the database out of your profiling.  Have each language version output the SQL text to a file.  Measure.  Next, take the SQL files and input them into the database, measure.  Determine if you can benchmark the programs talking directly to the database and measure.  My belief is that the speed doesn't have to do with the languages, but the interface or communications with the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a correct way for fast batch inserts in C++

Take less than 1 sec:

```
db.transaction();

for ( auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it  ) {
    std::string item = *it;
    qry.exec("INSERT INTO list VALUES ('"+item+"')");
}

db.commit();
```